# Is it legal to run Mac OS X version 10.6.3 Snow Leopard on windows?

Tags: mac, vmware-player, legal

Is it legal to run Mac OS X version 10.6.3 Snow Leopard on windows 7 with vmplayer?

Comment: Are you in the US? It depends on whether EULAs are legally binding in your jurisdiction...

Comment: You may want to read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6153/are-licensing-questions-license-questions-off-topic and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5908/what-is-the-place-to-ask-about-legal-issues-associated-with-using-software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not legal.  Even if you purchased a licensed copy of OS X, it is against the EULA to install it on anything other than an Apple Macintosh.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's legal to run Snow Leopard in a VM on Windows as long as you're running Windows on Apple Macintosh hardware (e.g. via Boot Camp).

Comment: Interesting... I guess its still Apple hardware...